# Matplotlib plot bad resolution when zooming

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, hierarchical-clustering

I am using matplotlib to plot hierarchical clusterings,

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram

def plot_dendrogram(model, **kwargs):

    # Children of hierarchical clustering
    children = model.children_

    # Distances between each pair of children
    # Since we don't have this information, we can use a uniform one for plotting
    distance = np.arange(children.shape[0])



    # The number of observations contained in each cluster level
    no_of_observations = np.arange(2, children.shape[0]+2)

    # Create linkage matrix and then plot the dendrogram
    linkage_matrix = np.column_stack([children, distance, no_of_observations]).astype(float)

    # Plot the corresponding dendrogram
    dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)

plt.figure(figsize=(100,100))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
plot_dendrogram(clustering, labels=liste_tags)
plt.show()
```

I can visualize the hierarchical clustering, however the quality and resolution of the plot is not good. Especially, when I save the plot and try to zoom in to see the labels for example.

I get this image :[image]

Answer (score 1):

[MatPlotLib Figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) object has a `dpi` parameter. Just set something like `plt.figure(figsize=(100,100), dpi=300)`.